# Git hook post-update writing but not updating work tree

Tags: git, deployment, githooks, git-post-receive, post-update

I'm trying to make git auto deploy to different directories depending on a branch that was pushed.
I have a remote bare repository, local repository and two directories where I whant the data to be deployed and updated with each push from local to remote repository.
I've added post-update hook:

```
#!/bin/sh


echo $1
echo "*UPDATE*"


case " $1 " in
*'refs/heads/develop'*)
        GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/git/public_html/example_deploy_dev git checkout develop webroot
        echo
        echo "Dev was pulled"
        echo
        ;;
esac

case " $1 " in
*'refs/heads/master'*)
        GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/git/public_html/example_deploy git checkout master webroot
        echo
        echo "Master was pulled"
        echo
        ;;
esac
```

It deploys just fine on first file creation, but doesn't update it when it's changed in directories which shold be deployed. Where do I miss smth?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The usual script for a [post update hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-update) is:

```
#! /bin/sh

update_master() {
    GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/git/public_html/example_deploy_dev git checkout master -- webroot
}

update_develop() {
    GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/git/public_html/example_deploy_dev git checkout develop -- webroot
}
for ref do
    case "$ref" in
    refs/heads/master) update_master;;
    refs/heads/test) update_test;;
    *) ;; # ignore other branches
    esac
done
```

Since that hook "takes a variable number of parameters, each of which is the name of ref that was actually updated.", you cannot rely only on `$1`.

Comment: thx for the reply! I had to 'esac' before 'done' to get it working, but it works the same as before: new files are added, but the old ones aren't updated... may be it is somehow relates to permittions?..

Comment: @YariG it should not, but do you see different ownership/right between new files and old ones in `/home/git/public_html/example_deploy_dev`?

Comment: @YariG do you need to checkout only webroot? Couldn't you try: `GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/git/public_html/example_deploy_dev git reset --hard` (warning this should override the all folder, not just webroot)

Comment: sure, I tried it: it updated the directory once but all further pushes behaved the same - adding new files but not updating old ones...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> checkout -f

```
#! /bin/sh

update_master() {
    GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/git/public_html/example_deploy_dev git checkout -f master -- webroot
}

update_develop() {
    GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/git/public_html/example_deploy_dev git checkout -f develop -- webroot
}
for ref do
    case "$ref" in
    refs/heads/master) update_master;;
    refs/heads/test) update_test;;
    *) ;; # ignore other branches
    esac
done
```